# Only mount files in docker that are present in host

Tags: linux, docker

At the moment I have to setup individual volume mounts for files I want to map.

```
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - ./example_app/settings.py:/app/example_app/settings.py
      - ./example_app/urls.py:/app/example_app/urls.py
```

I would like to be flexible and allow any file present inside the host /example_app/* be mapped to it's counterpart inside the container. I can't just map the whole folder as the build step installs a fresh app inside the container version each time.

My Dockerfile installs a fresh version of, in this case, Django in the container /example_project so files in the container must remain, and I essentially cascade any folder / file from host machine over the container version.

Is this possible?